# Django test-page returns 404 even though django is up and running

Tags: django, macos, osx-lion

I'm trying to set up my first django-dev in osx lion. It seems to be up and running:

```
Kristoffers-MacBook-Pro:django-test kristoffernolgren$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.1, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
^CKristoffers-MacBook-Pro:django-test kristoffernolgren$
```

but when I visit the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I get a "connection failed" error.

Comment: If Django immediately returns to the console then it is not up and running (i.e., that last line in your output should not be there). Does it automatically do that?

Comment: It seems you think that django app. server runs even after you press Ctrl+C. But it does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand that when cou press Ctrl+C you turn of the development server. Just don't press ctrl+c. Hopefully This will help someone else :)